# request-reply router is not working

Tags: mule

I am stuck up with a problem with the request-reply router in mule. I am using the mule release 3.4.0. The request-reply is used in a fork-join pattern , i followed this article on the blog site http://blogs.mulesoft.org/aggregation-with-mule-fork-and-join-pattern/.

```
    <request-reply>
      <all enableCorrelation="ALWAYS">
        <vm:outbound-endpoint path="PathA"/>
        <vm:outbound-endpoint path="PathB"/>
      </all>
      <vm:inbound-endpoint path="FinalResponse">
         <message-properties-transformer>
              <add-message-property key="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" value="2" />
         </message-properties-transformer>
         <collection-aggregator />
      </vm:inbound-endpoint>
    </request-reply>
```

The issue that i face is the processor placed after the request-reply is not reached.In mule i see 2 responses been sent to the FinalResponse vm endpoint. I tried placing my own custom aggregator in place of the collection-aggregator. But this is not reached. I am not sure how i can debug this issue. Please note that i have 2 such request-reply routers in two flows. Can someone help on this.

Adding the mule configuration. For abbrevity attaching only the parent flow and one of the child flow

**ParentFlow**

```
    <flow name="ParentFlow" doc:name="ParentFlow" tracking:enable-default-events="true">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="${SourceFilePath}"
        connector-ref="ParentFlowInboundConnector" 
        responseTimeout="10000" tracking:enable-default-events="true">
        <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="${REGEX}" caseSensitive="false"/>

    </file:inbound-endpoint>

    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    <message-properties-transformer
        doc:name="Message Properties">
        <add-message-property key="Source_System" value="XXX" />
        <add-message-property key="publisherName" value="YYY" />
        <add-message-property key="FlowName" value="ZZZ"/>
    </message-properties-transformer>
    <!-- This would store the message in the db -->
    <wire-tap>
        <vm:outbound-endpoint path="PERSITENCE.OUT"/>
    </wire-tap>

    <request-reply>
            <all doc:name="Move the message to all endpoints" enableCorrelation="ALWAYS">
                <vm:outbound-endpoint path="PathA"/>
                <vm:outbound-endpoint path="PathB"/>
                <vm:outbound-endpoint path="PathC"/>
                <vm:outbound-endpoint path="PathD"/>
            </all>
        <vm:inbound-endpoint path="Response">               
            <message-properties-transformer>                    
                <add-message-property key="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" value="4" />                
            </message-properties-transformer>               
            <collection-aggregator failOnTimeout="false" doc:name="Collection Aggregator" />
        </vm:inbound-endpoint>

    </request-reply>
    <component class="ProcessorA"  />
    <component class="ProcessorB" />
    <exception-strategy ref="Exception Strategy" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy"/>
</flow>
```

**Child Flow**

```
<flow name="PathA" doc:name="PathA">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="PathA" >
        <vm:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
    </vm:inbound-endpoint>
    <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">                  
        <add-message-property key="originalFilename_processing" value="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" />                
    </message-properties-transformer>
    <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">                  
        <add-message-property key="directory" value="#[message.inboundProperties.directory]" />             
    </message-properties-transformer>

    <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
        <add-message-property key="Destination_System" value="XXX" />
    </message-properties-transformer>

    <file:outbound-endpoint path="${OutPathA}" connector-ref="FileConnector_1" 
        tracking:enable-default-events="true"/>

    <!--Send email alerts -->
     <all doc:name="All" >
        <processor-chain>
            <message-property-filter pattern="turnOffEmail=false" caseSensitive="true" doc:name="Message Property"/>
            <custom-transformer class="com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.VelocityTemplateResolver" doc:name="Java">
                <spring:property name="flowName" value="PPPP"/>
            </custom-transformer>
            <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="${SMTP_HOSTNAME}" port="${SMTP_PORT}" user="${SMTP_USERNAME}" password="${SMTP_PASSWORD}" to="${TO_ADDRESS}" from="${FROM_ADDRESS}" subject="${MAIL_SUBJECT}" cc="${MAIL_CC_ADDRESS}" bcc="${MAIL_BCC_ADDRESS}" responseTimeout="10000" transformer-refs="emailVelocityMessageTransformer"  tracking:enable-default-events="true"/>
        </processor-chain>
        <processor-chain>
            <message-property-filter pattern="turnOffEmail=false" caseSensitive="true" doc:name="Message Property"/>
            <custom-transformer class="com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.VelocityTemplateResolver" doc:name="Java">
                <spring:property name="flowName" value="FlowName"/>
            </custom-transformer>
            <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="${SMTP_HOSTNAME}" port="${SMTP_PORT}" user="${SMTP_USERNAME}" password="${SMTP_PASSWORD}" to="${MAIL_TO_ADDRESS}" from="${MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS}" subject="${MAIL_SUBJECT}" cc="${MAIL_CC_ADDRESS}" bcc="${BCC_ADDRESS}" responseTimeout="10000" transformer-refs="emailVelocityMessageTransformer" tracking:enable-default-events="true"/>
        </processor-chain>
        <processor-chain>
            <message-property-filter pattern="turnOffEmail=false" caseSensitive="true" doc:name="Message Property"/>
            <custom-transformer class="com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.VelocityTemplateResolver" doc:name="Java">
                <spring:property name="flowName" value="AAAA"/>
            </custom-transformer>
            <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="${SMTP_HOSTNAME}" port="${SMTP_PORT}" user="${SMTP_USERNAME}" password="${SMTP_PASSWORD}" to="${MAIL_TO_ADDRESS}" from="${MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS}" subject="${MAIL_SUBJECT}" cc="${MAIL_CC_ADDRESS}" bcc="${MAIL_BCC_ADDRESS}" responseTimeout="10000" transformer-refs="emailVelocityMessageTransformer" tracking:enable-default-events="true"/>
        </processor-chain>
    </all>
    <rollback-exception-strategy doc:name="Rollback Exception Strategy" maxRedeliveryAttempts="${MAX_REDELIVERY_ATTEMPTS}" enableNotifications="false">
        <logger message="==Rollback log ===" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </rollback-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

Comment: If my vm endpoints are transactional PathA and PathB will this cause a problem

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of the the problem is **correlation ID**.

You might want to inspect the correlation ID of the messages sent out to Path A and Path B. The message received on FinalResponse VM inbound endpoint needs to have the same correlation ID, otherwise it won't be accepted as a response to the messages previously sent. In other words the request-reply will NOT accept just anything in the inbound-endpoint but just the message matching the correlation ID of the posted on outbound-endpoint with the request-reply router.

You can set the custom correlation ID using this --

```
<set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" value="some-correlation-id" />
```

Comment: I am not setting a custom correlatiom id, why will the id gemerated by Mule change.I am looking at the configuration I provided above.

Comment: I am saying just make sure that you set the original correlation ID on the messages that come to your FinalResponse VM queue. In some scenarios the correlation ID gets lost, for example if your message going out somewhere like JMS.

Comment: The patha and pathb are vm emdpoints  and final destination are file endpoints can the correlation id change here.Should I take care of this

Comment: Need to look at your code for that. Can update your post and share the code, on how you are consuming messages from PathA and PathB and how you are putting messages on FinalResponse VM queue.

Comment: I have posted the mule configuration for ab-brevity i have added only the parent flow and one of the child flows and skipped some processors in between

Comment: I tried logging the correlation id in the child flows but they are the same using a logger component.

Comment: This is not a issue with the request-reply router but seems to be some other blocking issue which i have raised as a separate question.So this is no longer an issue.